# Select from two tables and result in two arrays with PDO?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I need to display data on a page from two different tables in a database and populate two different dropdown lists. I've created the code for it with PDO and everything works as it should, so no problem there. My question is if there is a better/nicer way of doing this than in my example. Or is this the best/only logical way of doing it with PDO?

```
<?php 
     $stmt = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_cars");
     $stmt2 = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_houses");
     $stmt2->execute();
     $stmt->execute();
     $cars = $stmt->fetchAll();
     $houses = $stmt2->fetchAll();
 ?>


 <select name="cars">
 <?php foreach ($cars as $row): ?>
    <option><?=$row["name"]?></option>
 <?php endforeach ?>
 </select>

 <select name="houses">
 <?php foreach ($houses as $row): ?>
    <option><?=$row["name"]?></option>
 <?php endforeach ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: I think its better to use functions for both of them u can use any where easily

Comment: Or u can use one single query select * from tbl_car, tbl_house

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty Not really, but i will check it out. Thanks

Comment: If you're only going to use the 'name' column then don't select the rest.

Comment: @devpro I'm only going to use the result and queries on this specific page, so I dont know if there is need for that? And if I use one singe query, how can i put  the result in two different arrays?

Comment: Dont forget the backticks also

Comment: @ethrbunny the tables only contain id and name, and I need the ID later on i think

Comment: Than no need two array u will get th result from one array

Comment: But how can I then populate two different dropdown list from one array?